# notify-send/notification-daemon: disable tray icon

Tags: openbox, lxde, notifications, panel, libnotify

When I use `notify-send` to send a simple message to `notification-daemon`:

```
notify-send "hello"
```

it not only displays the message but also creates a system tray icon, as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

This icon will stay in the system tray until I click on it and select "clear all notifications". This icon completely defeats the purpose of `notify-send` as unobtrusive notification. I have used `notify-send` few years ago and I am sure it did not have any tray icon back than. Needles to say, this is absolutely annoying.

I have found that I can use `transient` option

```
notify-send --hint=int:transient:1 hello
```

Which makes the icon disappear after a certain time. This is better, but still not acceptable.

**Is there any way to get rid of the tray icon entirely?**

I am using LXDE on Debian Wheezy

Some answers suggest, this is caused by my desktop environment (LXDE).

I find it hard to believe. I still suspect this is caused by notification daemon. I have downloaded sources for `notification-daemon` package, and there in the `CHANGELOG` I see, among other things:

> - Added better support for attaching context notifications to an icon on
>       the system tray, even when it moves. Patch by Colin Walters.

Which seems to be the "feature" that I am complaining about.

Can anybody advice how to disable systray notification in `notification-daemon`? When I grep the sources for `tray` or `systray`, I don't find anything. I don't know where to start.

Comment: your tip for transient notifications is great

Comment: I added a `-t 150` after your `transient` option which makes it disappear after 150 ms. Good enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, you are right in attributing the system tray icon to `notification-daemon`. If you are not happy with the icon, try another notification daemon. Notifications work on the basis of client/server. Any notification client can communicate with any compatible server.

I myself am using `dunst` and I am very happy with that. It does not have any system tray notification.

There are several notification daemons, `notification-daemon` being only one of them. In Debian, you can list them with following command:

```
$ apt-cache search notification | grep daemon | grep notification
dunst - minimalistic notification daemon
inosync - notification-based directory synchronization daemon
notification-daemon - daemon for displaying passive pop-up notifications
notify-osd - daemon that displays passive pop-up notifications
xfce4-notifyd - simple, visually-appealing notification daemon for Xfce
```

I can recommend `dunst`. It is a minimalistic, yet highly configurable
 notification daemon.

Answer (score 3):

That icon has nothing, *nothing* to do with libnotify, nor dbus. This is entirely dependent of your DM/WM (I'm guessing cinnamon, but could be wrong) and dbus/libnotify can't do anything to control it.

For comparison: XFCE doesn't use such icon, and I'm aware that GNOME Shell does show a icon independently what method you use.

If you need to get rid of the icon, consult the documentation of your desktop environment, through if you are using a derivation of GNOME 3 it may be not possible.

Comment: I am using `LXDE`.

Comment: I thought, LXDE only provides the system tray for applications to use. It is up to the applications whether/how they use the system tray.

Comment: @MartinVegter I've checked the reference again, is up to the notify server how to deal with the notifications they retrieve. I've found nothing in the reference that indicates otherwise. What I saw was that you can use hints so the item is destroyed along with the bubble, which in your case should dismiss the icon, but I figure you don't want the icon in first place either.

Comment: Yeah, that icon does not appear for me in lxpanel. I've never seen it.

Comment: I think the status icon is brought by the `indicator plugin` of a panel. Remove this plugin and the status icon will disappear... along with all possibly useful indications, I guess.

Comment: @Nasha - how can I remove the `indicator plugin`? Do I have to recompile my own `lxpanel` package ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that with LXDE but you don't have to recompile anything. I assume what you're looking for lies somewhere in the bottom panel properties — i.e. the bar at the bottom; under GNOME, those bars are named "panels" and from what I see in your screenshot it looks much like it. Try right clicking the bottom panel and search for "properties" or "settings". Maybe there is also a global "Settings" section in your environment's menu that links to the bottom panel properties.

Comment: To say it has _nothing_ to do with dbus is incorrect.  The notification daemon (`notify-osd`, `notification-daemon` or others) _listens_ to dbus messages and displays the ones it thinks the user should see.  e.g., I can set the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and direct a notification coming from one display onto another display (a VNC session, for example).  It is _very_ handy in some of my more interconnected setups.

Comment: @DavidDombrowsky the icon itself is a selection of how the system you use decides. Dbus doesn't affect it, as you discovered in your own answer. The icon depends on the notification handler.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had the opposite request.  I *wanted* the list of notifications to show up.  Turns out the default in lxde (or maybe ubuntu) is `notify-osd`, which doesn't show this icon or the history of messages sent by anything, including `notify-send`.

I switched it to `notification-daemon` and it does exactly what I want it to do.  Not sure how to hack the startup scripts or settings to get `lxde` to do it automatically, but that's a solvable problem.

Comment: I am using Lubuntu 18.04 and I would like to get a notification icon with the list of notifications, as I use quite a few software generating notifications which I don't always see right away.
I have tryed to install `notification-daemon` but it was already installed so nothing changed. Any other ideas on how to activate an icon with a notifications list  ?

Comment: It's possible that the default notification handler is grabbing them.  I had to make sure that all others (e.g. `notify-osd`) were REMOVED from the system, and then `notification-daemon`  seems to work automatically.  It shows the history of notifications also, which is nice.

Comment: It was `xfce4-notifyd` that was running and it did not get listed by the command `apt-cache search notification | grep daemon | grep notification` as the text is in translated in French (I am running LXDE in French).
I eventually found it and removed it (and killed it). I installed `notification-daemon` and started it manually with `/usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon start` and it works fine now !

Comment: I will see after next reboot if it does not start automagically, I will add it to the autostart apps in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

Answer (score -3):

Use the --icon= flag with a path to a transparent image. Combine that with the short timeout and you don't see anything.

Comment: No, [the `--icon=` option](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/12/ubuntu-notify-send/) is for the icon *within* the tooltip.